# Opening multiple PDF documents using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, cmd, acrobat

I am trying to open several PDF documents using a simple batch file:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
cd Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW1.pdf
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW2.pdf
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW3.pdf
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW4.pdf
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW5.pdf
Acrord32.exe C:\Users\BW6.pdf
EXIT
```

The above batch file opens the first PDF only, then waits until I close it for the next PDF file to open. How can I have all the PDF documents open at the same time? (Like going to Acrobat Reader, file->Open->xx.pdf)

Answer (score 15):

Use `start`:

```
start acrord32.exe 1.pdf
start acrord32.exe 2.pdf
start acrord32.exe 3.pdf
```

Or even (as Johannes Rössel suggests in the comment below):

```
start 1.pdf
start 2.pdf
start 3.pdf
```

Would probably work as well (depending on your default PDF viewer).

Note that when using `start` you have to be careful when using quoted arguments, as the following won't work (the first quoted argument is interpreted as the title for a new console window):

```
start "1.pdf"
```

Instead you'll have to do the following:

```
start "" "1.pdf"
```

It's an annoying quirk of `start`, but you have to effectively supply a dummy title in this case to properly open the specified file (even though the title is unnecessary as this won't create a new console window).

[A list of other available batch commands.](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)

Comment: In that case you can probably use start alone on the PDF files as well. Depending on the default application for them, though :)

Answer (score 2):

For me it works even without the `start` command. I use:

```
c:\path\to\my.pdf
```

in cmd.exe windows frequently, and it always opens Acrobat Reader (my default viewer on Windows). In a batchfile I've written to generate PDF via Ghostscript, my last two lines are:

```
"%ouptutpath%\%outputfile%.pdf"
"%outputpath%\%outputfile%-optimized.pdf"
```

which automatically opens both generated PDFs in two different Reader windows. (My `%outputpath%` contains spaces, the `%outputfile%` may also have some...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried whether Acrobat Reader allows for more files on the commandline, ie.

```
start acrord32.exe 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

Using start did the trick. I had to use start as many times as the number of pdf documents I want to open. For some reason

start acrord32.exe 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf

opens only the first document. So I guess Acrobat reader might not allow for more files on the command line.

I rally appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answers.

I also tried below, working fine:

start /B excel.exe "D:\my first file.xlsx" "E:\my second file.xlsx" "D:\working folder\my third file.xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

For every pdf file in the specified directory, use the start command on that file:

```
for %f in ("C:\Users\*.pdf") do start %f
```

As per the Microsoft Docs:

> For runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
>
> `for {%variable|%%variable} in (set) do command [ CommandLineOptions]`

Comment: I get the error `("C:\Users\*.pdf") was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I also got this error

Answer (score -1):

This is follow up to the answer given by JSON C11 above.
I checked in Windows 10 OS, the command given as below with the error ("C:\Users*.pdf") was unexpected at this time.
for %f ("C:\Users*.pdf") do start %f
What is missing is 'in'. Correct code is...

```
    for %f in ("C:\Users\*.pdf") do start %f
```

If you have a binary to open that particular type of file, and you like to open in maximized view, you can use the following code.

```
    for %f in ("C:\Users\*.pdf") do start /max <path to binary> %f
```