# how to open multiple PDF files with a single batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I want to open more than 3 pdf files from a single batch script.

I wrote the following code:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
cd Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer
start "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample\one.pdf" "C:\Users\Desktop\sample\two.pdf"
EXIT
```

…but it opens only the first pdf file for some reason.

How do I open multiple files?

Comment: Already answered there :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695603/opening-multiple-pdf-documents-using-batch-file

Comment: First enter `Start /?` at the Command prompt to find out how it works.

Comment: @CharlyDefaivre: Not with the particular problem they have, which is that they have quoted arguments.

Comment: @jeb, I didn't think that we could mark answers as duplicates when there was no accepted answer!

Comment: @Compo: The *question* is the dupe, not any answer

Comment: Without an accepted answer, it should only be linked to as in Charly's comment. _The question shouldn't be closed regardless because it isn't an exact duplicate as @Joey alludes to_. The issue is as much how to use the `Start` command as it is how to open multiple pdf's.

Comment: @Compo: I've edited the top answer of the other question to include the answer to this one, though.

Comment: @Joey, you've edited a nine year old answer unnecessarily then! The edit does nothing to explain the information readiliy visible from doing what I mentioned in my opening comment; the term 'title' doesn't get mentioned anywhere in your edited answer or indeed on that page.

Comment: @Compo, then re-open this one (or you could have amended the edit on the other answer to fix your perceived problems). As it stands I have no problems with the dupe vote right now. IMHO it isn't really necessary to have the same question multiple times with only very slight variation (in this case, quoted or unquoted arguments).

Comment: @Joey, sorry, it's not my intention to edit an old answer to match a new question, that alone is illogical. It is even less so when done to justify a question with no accepted answer being marked as an exact duplicate, when it is only a similar or part duplicated question.

Comment: But it *does* match this question. Both have the same goal, they only differ in the constraints upon invocation. Adding information how to deal with those constraints is IMHO not illogical, it makes the other answer *better*.

Comment: @Compo You're right- There isn't an accepted answer, but there is still a correct answer, that should be enough.